# Explicitly setting build.number for artifactory-builds

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

How can I publish an artifact to Artifactory using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin, and explicitly set the property build.number, so it can be referenced for promotion by the Artifactory REST API?

Problem:

When I publish an artifact(with the Jenkins Artifactory plugin), the build.number property of the artifact is set to the build number of the Jenkins job, which published it.
When I want another Job to promote the artifact to another repository, I need this number.
I want to set the build number to the number of the first job, because I am already propagating it through all jobs.
Setting "build.number=${...}" explicitly in the field "Deployment properties" of the Jenkins Artifactory plugin produces an artifact with the correct build number(which I can see in the web-interface), but:

The promotion script for the Artifactory REST API is unable to locate the artifact with explicitly set build number.